# How do I pass extra arguments to PyQt GUI functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to build a simple 1x1 practice tool for my kid with some graphical widgets. As shown in the image below a "New Problem" button generates internally 2 random numbers and displays it in a text field. The user has to provide the result next to =. With the "Check Result", I want a conditional instruction that makes:

1. if result is correct print "Correct! Result is ..." and change background color to green.
2. if result is wrong print "..." and change background color to red

[image]

Now, the problem is: I am generating the random numbers in a function that is connected to the "New Problem" button. If I hit "Check Result" those numbers will not be passed to the "check result" button. Without class definition I usually pass values by return, however, here with class self it does not work.

- Question1: What is the best way to solve this problem ?
- Question2: I have no clue how to change the color of those text fields.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The code I have got so far is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import new_design6  # translated from Qt designer (not relevant for this question)

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow,new_design6.Ui_MainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.exit_app.clicked.connect(self.exit_application)
        self.get_new_problem.clicked.connect(self.generate_new_problem)
        self.check_result.clicked.connect(self.check_problem_result)


    def generate_new_problem(self):
        # clear each field 
        self.show_problem.clear()
        self.input_result.clear()
        self.show_result.clear()

        u = int(np.random.randint(0,11,1))
        v = int(np.random.randint(0,11,1))
        w = str(u) + " x " + str(v)

        self.show_problem.setReadOnly(True)
        self.show_problem.setPlainText(w)
        # how to pass my random numbers ?
        return(u,v) #*---> Problem line1* 


    def check_problem_result(self,u,v): #*---> Problem line1* 
        input_result_number=self.input_result.toPlainText()
        result=int(input_result_number)

        # here I'd like to have a conditional question to check if result is correkt or wrong
        if (result == u*v):
            result_string="Correct! Result is:  " + str(result)
            self.show_result.setPlainText(result_string)
        else: 
            result_string="Wrong! Result is:  " + str(result) + "Try another one"


    def exit_application(self):
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appropriate way would be to create a class that manages operations:

```
class Operation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = []

    def setParams(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def process(self):
        # processing
        u, v = self.params
        result = u*v
        return result 

    def toString(self):
        return "{}x{}".format(*self.params)
```

Then an object of that kind is created as an attribute of the widget and the logic is handled, as it is a property that can be accessed in the whole scope of the class.

To change the color I use the QPalette of the widget as shown in the following code:

```
class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow,new_design6.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.exit_app.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.get_new_problem.clicked.connect(self.generate_new_problem)
        self.check_result.clicked.connect(self.check_problem_result)
        self.operation = Operation()
        self.show_problem.setReadOnly(True)

    def generate_new_problem(self):
        self.show_problem.clear()
        self.input_result.clear()
        self.show_result.clear()
        pal = self.show_result.palette()
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.show_result.setPalette(pal)
        u = int(np.random.randint(0,11,1))
        v = int(np.random.randint(0,11,1))
        params = u, v
        self.operation.setParams(params)        
        self.show_problem.setPlainText(self.operation.toString())

    def check_problem_result(self):
        input_result_number = self.input_result.toPlainText()
        result = int(input_result_number)
        pal = self.show_result.palette()
        if self.operation.process() == result:
            result_string="Correct! Result is:  {}".format(result)
            pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtCore.Qt.green)
        else: 
            result_string="Wrong! Result is: {} Try another one".format(result)
            pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.show_result.setPlainText(result_string)
        self.show_result.setPalette(pal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I just added your code and run it. It only invoked the GUI, however, when I pressed the 'New Problem' button it killed the kernel w/o information why. Is the following hierarchy correct?  --> 'class ExampleApp' def def def def comes first, then I added 'class Object' as it is an attribute of those widgets ?

Comment: @cyclomen Share your complete project to review what the problem is through dropbox or similar.

Comment: No Problem, nothing special - see here "new_design6.py" : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O9-XELAGsPlov2s18M6mjdmS71JzbMQD/view?usp=sharing  and  main2.py: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oN-0iazJgG_ABgOKwzzsWrfX2jwn6bz1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @cyclomen  The error is simple, you need to import QtCore, to fix it change `from PyQt4 import QtGui` to `from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore`

Comment: Great, appreciate it!